# Determine location of next page when user navigates away, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, dom-events, session-state

I'm trying to determine the location of the next page when the user navigates away from the current page. The use-case here is a ASP.NET session providing persistent login. One requirement is that users must have the option to automatically logout when navigating to a different domain.

My initial approach was to listen for `onbeforeunload` on `window` and then use AJAX to call the appropriate server-side script to abandon the session. The problem is that this requires checking all anchors on the page to determine if we are navigating to a page within the domain, in which case the session should not be abandoned. This would include ALL events which could activate a link. Something like:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){
   //Check if user activated an anchor on page with href attribute within domain.
   //If not, use AJAX to request server to abandon session.
}, false);
```

The approach above doesn't seem like the best solution. Is there any better way to determine the location of the next page?

Comment: If you have links that leave your site then make them logout and redirect to the external url, rather than just change the url.  Eg.  Instead of a link to `http://www.google.com` have a link to `logout.aspx?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`

Comment: This seems like a good approach. Destroying the session on external links will mean less event handlers on the client.  The remaining problem is how to deal with the case where the user closes the browser/tab or uses a bookmark to navigate away. One really simple way to handle these cases uses a single flag on the client. The flag is set to false onload. Any internal link sets this flag to true onclick. (Eg. all menu buttons). The beforeunload handler then only needs to check this flag and request the server to invalidate session if the flag is false.